# Dropdownlist Dynamically Created into Repeater Dynamically Created asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, selectedindexchanged

I am creating a dynamically repeater during the creation of this repeater I create some dropdownlists with autopostback = true, and add the handler selectindexchanged. I wonder how to keep bind the repeater inside (! IsNotPostBack) without losing the repeater information. In summary if I keep bind the repeater in notpostback, when I change the dropdownlist the repeater is not rendered.
Well confused? I will post part of the code:

Default.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindRepeater2();
        }
    }

private void BindRepeater2()
{
    Repeater rContainer = null;
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    HtmlGenericControl table = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "CompApp_TableScroll");
    table.Attributes.Add("class", "CompApp_DataTable");
    table.Attributes.Add("width", "100%");
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DropDown", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(25, "Rk", "Gurgaon");
        dt.Rows.Add(50, "Sachin", "Noida");
        dt.Rows.Add(10, "Nitin", "Noida");
        dt.Rows.Add(21, "Aditya", "Meerut");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rContainer = new Repeater();
            rContainer.DataSource = dt;
            rContainer.DataBind();
            foreach (DataTable dtCluster in ds.Tables)
            {
                rContainer = new Repeater();
                rContainer.ItemTemplate = new RepeaterTemplate2(ListItemType.Item);
                rContainer.HeaderTemplate = new RepeaterTemplate2(ListItemType.Header);
                rContainer.FooterTemplate = new RepeaterTemplate2(ListItemType.Footer);
                rContainer.DataSource = dtCluster;
                table.Controls.Add(rContainer);
            }
            div.Controls.Add(table);
        }
        div1.Controls.Add(div);
        rContainer.ItemDataBound += rContainer_ItemDataBound;
        rContainer.ID = "rpt1";
        rContainer.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

void rContainer_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddl");
        ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

private void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl2 = new DropDownList();
    ddl2 = (DropDownList)sender;
    Response.Write(ddl2.SelectedValue);
}
```

RepeaterTemplate2.cs

```
public class RepeaterTemplate2 : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
{
    ListItemType vTemplateItemType = ListItemType.Separator;

    public RepeaterTemplate2(ListItemType pListItemType)
    {
        vTemplateItemType = pListItemType;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        Literal lc = new Literal();
        HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
        HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
        switch (vTemplateItemType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:
                td.InnerHtml = "<u>EmpID</u>";
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
                td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                td.InnerHtml = "<u>Name</u>";
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
                td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                td.InnerHtml = "<u>Address</u>";
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
                td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                td.InnerHtml = "<u>DropdDown</u>";
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:
                break;

            case ListItemType.Item:
                ; break;
        }
        tr.DataBinding += new EventHandler(lc_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(tr);
    }

    private void lc_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl tr = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;
        RepeaterItem vContainer = (RepeaterItem)tr.NamingContainer;
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)vContainer.DataItem;
        if (row != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.DataView.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                    ddl.ID = "ddl";
                    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("valor 1", "1"));
                    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("valor 2", "2"));
                    td.Controls.Add(ddl);
                }
                else
                {
                    td.InnerHtml = row[i].ToString();
                }
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to recreate the dynamic controls every postback and you have to do it early enough in the page  lifecycle so they are populated with the user data submitted.  You should research page lifecyle and dynamic controls to get an understanding of how to accomplish this.  There are plenty of answers to this problem already on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm having problems with postbacks, since there are dropdowns with information that is passed by parameter to the method that creates the repeater.
I've tried everything from Page_Load to Page_Init.
I believe it is not possible to carry out what I want in asp.net.